# JSHint "not defined" errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, jshint

I have this function that I'm using to validate a contact form, but I am getting a ton of "not defined" errors when I run it through JSHint.  I am quite a jquery noob and I' not sure how these are supposed to be defined.

```
(function ($, document, undefined) {
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Place ID's of all required fields here.
    required = ["name", "email", "message"];
    // If using an ID other than #email or #error then replace it here
    email = $("#email");
    errornotice = $("#error");
    // The text to show up within a field when it is incorrect
    emptyerror = "Please fill out this field.";
    emailerror = "Please enter a valid e-mail.";

    $("#theform").submit(function(){
        //Validate required fields
        for (i=0;i<required.length;i++) {
            var input = $('#'+required[i]);
            if ((input.val() == "") || (input.val() == emptyerror)) {
                input.addClass("needsfilled");
                input.val(emptyerror);
                errornotice.fadeIn(750);
            } else {
                input.removeClass("needsfilled");
            }
        }
        // Validate the e-mail.
        if (!/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/.test(email.val())) {
            email.addClass("needsfilled");
            email.val(emailerror);
        }

        //if any inputs on the page have the class 'needsfilled' the form will not submit
        if ($(":input").hasClass("needsfilled")) {
            return false;
        } else {
            errornotice.hide();
            return true;
        }
    });

    // Clears any fields in the form when the user clicks on them
    $(":input").focus(function(){       
       if ($(this).hasClass("needsfilled") ) {
            $(this).val("");
            $(this).removeClass("needsfilled");
       }
    });
});
})(jQuery, document);
```

Here are a couple examples:

from the form data - 'required' is not defined.

```
required = ["name", "email", "message"];
```

'i' is not defined.

```
for (i=0;i<required.length;i++) {
```

and 'email' is not defined.

```
if (!/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/.test(email.val())) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define the variables with "var":

```
var required = ["name", "email", "message"];
for(var i...
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is probably ultimately a style question. Using variables without a `var` declaration obviously means that you are using an undeclared variable. In some cases this is done on purpose to generate variables with *global scope*. This can of course (in a *cleaner way*) be achieved by declaring the variables somewhere *outside* of all closures with `var email;`.